# Steering comments from crashing into the rocky shores of a discussion

Tags: support, comments

Is it practical to determine when to stop posting/trading comments on an answer on Stack Overflow? Are there guidelines for how we can avoid a drawn out comment stream?

Basically, if the comments look like they are evolving into a new question or perhaps even a discussion, is it acceptable to formulate a truly **new** question and post the new question?

I just want to keep the quality of my questions/comments good and on topic.

Comment: This is indeed a support question in this way, it's okay. ♪

Comment: @random thanks for your edits! It's clear, concise, and to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes comments can go on for a while and I think that's OK. It's when it delves into namecalling or general disrepect for another person that is when it should stop.